# How to transform multiple documents contained in a single file using xsltproc?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a file with several XML documents in a single line. Something like:

```
<entity id ="1"><attribute name="x">1</attribute><attribute name="y">2</attribute></entity>
<entity id name="2"><attribute name="x">5</attribute><attribute name="y">6</attribute></entity>
<entity id name="3"><attribute name="x">8</attribute><attribute name="y">9</attribute></entity>
```

I would like to apply a transformation using **xlstproc** but it gives me a parsing error since it is not a well formed XML (no single root element) because each line is a complete XML document.

Is there a way I can do this without putting each document in a single file?

I thought of including a dummy root element but I would like to avoid this.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: BTW, the above XML is not even a set of well-formed documents. `<attribute ="y">` is missing something.

Comment: I edited the question. It was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Linux/UNIX/Posix shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Assuming x.xsl is your transform,
# and x.xml contains one well-formed doc per line,
# the following loop will perform the transform
# on each line individually

while read i; do
    echo $i | xsltproc x.xsl -
done < x.xml
```